# Self-diffeomorphisms of fibered knot complements

Tags: knot-theory, 3-manifolds, mapping-class-groups

A knot $K \subset S^3$ is [fibered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibered_knot) if the complement $S^3 \setminus K$ of (a small open neighborhood of) $K$ is a fiber bundle over $S^1$. (The fiber will be a surface with one boundary component.)

> Q: If $K$ is fibered, can we construct a diffeomorphism from the knot complement to itself?

One naive attempt is to pick an automorphism of a fiber and then try to extend it to the whole bundle, but it seems likely that this rarely works. However, there are a couple "special" automorphisms of a fiber: the hyperelliptic involution, and the (non-orientation-preserving) "flip across a plane." Do either of these extend to a fibered knot complement?

Comment: Your question seems pretty vague.  But yes, sometimes there's infinitely many distinct isotopy classes of diffeomorphisms of fibred knots.  Various ways of enumerating and describing the group structure of these diffeomorphism groups are given in my own and Allen Hatcher's papers.  For fibred knots you can think of the diffeomorphism groups in terms of the automorphisms of the Thurstson reduction system of the fibre. I'm not sure there's much to say.  Sometimes yes, sometimes no. Anything can happen.

Comment: @RyanBudney I certainly agree that it's vague (it's also ignorant). I guess another way to ask what I meant is "is the automorphism group of a fibered knot complement always nonempty?"

Comment: Sometimes the automorphism group is trivial, even for fibred knots.  For example $9_{32}$ is fibred with no automorphisms (up to isotopy).

Comment: There are some very subtle questions lurking in the deep here.  For example, if you have a link in $S^3$ you can study the representation of the symmetry group (automorphisms of $(S^3,L)$ on the diffeomorphism group of the link itself $L$.  What kinds of representations you can get when you put various restrictions on the link type are hard open problems.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely helpful. And it does sound reasonable that there are quite subtle questions here (which mine is certainly not).